# curl_init issue in php

Tags: php, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, linux-mint

When i am going to access paypal(payment gateway) from local host i got an error like

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in
>   /var/www/html/pp/temp/paypalfunctions.php:331 Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/pp/temp/paypalfunctions.php(90):
>   hash_call('SetExpressCheck...', '&PAYMENTREQUEST...') #1
>   /var/www/html/pp/temp/expresscheckout.php(49):
>   CallShortcutExpressCheckout(NULL, 'USD', 'Sale', 'http://localhos...',
>   'http://localhos...') #2 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/html/pp/temp/paypalfunctions.php on line 331

I have **paypalfunctions.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


  /*   * ******************************************
    PayPal API Module

    Defines all the global variables and the wrapper functions
   * ****************************************** */
  $PROXY_HOST = '127.0.0.1';
  $PROXY_PORT = '808';

  $SandboxFlag = true;

  //'------------------------------------
  //' PayPal API Credentials
  //' Replace <API_USERNAME> with your API Username
  //' Replace <API_PASSWORD> with your API Password
  //' Replace <API_SIGNATURE> with your Signature
  //'------------------------------------
  $API_UserName = "APU_USERNAME";
  $API_Password = "API_PASS";
  $API_Signature = "API_SIGNATURE";

  // BN Code    is only applicable for partners
  $sBNCode = "PP-ECWizard";


  /*    
    ' Define the PayPal Redirect URLs.
    '   This is the URL that the buyer is first sent to do authorize payment with their paypal account
    '   change the URL depending if you are testing on the sandbox or the live PayPal site
    '
    ' For the sandbox, the URL is       https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=
    ' For the live site, the URL is        https://www.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=
   */

  if ($SandboxFlag == true) {
       $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp";
       $PAYPAL_URL = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=";
  } else {
       $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
       $PAYPAL_URL = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=";
  }

  $USE_PROXY = false;
  $version = "64";

  if (session_id() == "")
       session_start();

  /* An express checkout transaction starts with a token, that
    identifies to PayPal your transaction
    In this example, when the script sees a token, the script
    knows that the buyer has already authorized payment through
    paypal.  If no token was found, the action is to send the buyer
    to PayPal to first authorize payment
   */

  /*
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for the SetExpressCheckout API Call.
    ' Inputs:
    '       paymentAmount:      Total value of the shopping cart
    '       currencyCodeType:   Currency code value the PayPal API
    '       paymentType:        paymentType has to be one of the following values: Sale or Order or Authorization
    '       returnURL:          the page where buyers return to after they are done with the payment review on PayPal
    '       cancelURL:          the page where buyers return to when they cancel the payment review on PayPal
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   */

  function CallShortcutExpressCheckout($paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, $cancelURL) {
       //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       // Construct the parameter string that describes the SetExpressCheckout API call in the shortcut implementation

       $nvpstr = "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=" . $paymentAmount;
       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=" . $paymentType;
       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&RETURNURL=" . $returnURL;
       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CANCELURL=" . $cancelURL;
       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=" . $currencyCodeType;
       //echo $nvpstr;exit;
       $_SESSION["currencyCodeType"] = $currencyCodeType;
       $_SESSION["PaymentType"] = $paymentType;
       //'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
       //' Make the API call to PayPal
       //' If the API call succeded, then redirect the buyer to PayPal to begin to authorize payment.  
       //' If an error occured, show the resulting errors
       //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       $resArray = hash_call("SetExpressCheckout", $nvpstr);
       $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
       if ($ack == "SUCCESS" || $ack == "SUCCESSWITHWARNING") {
            $token = urldecode($resArray["TOKEN"]);
            $_SESSION['TOKEN'] = $token;
       }

       return $resArray;
  }

  /*
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for the SetExpressCheckout API Call.
    ' Inputs:
    '       paymentAmount:      Total value of the shopping cart
    '       currencyCodeType:   Currency code value the PayPal API
    '       paymentType:        paymentType has to be one of the following values: Sale or Order or Authorization
    '       returnURL:          the page where buyers return to after they are done with the payment review on PayPal
    '       cancelURL:          the page where buyers return to when they cancel the payment review on PayPal
    '       shipToName:     the Ship to name entered on the merchant's site
    '       shipToStreet:       the Ship to Street entered on the merchant's site
    '       shipToCity:         the Ship to City entered on the merchant's site
    '       shipToState:        the Ship to State entered on the merchant's site
    '       shipToCountryCode:  the Code for Ship to Country entered on the merchant's site
    '       shipToZip:          the Ship to ZipCode entered on the merchant's site
    '       shipToStreet2:      the Ship to Street2 entered on the merchant's site
    '       phoneNum:           the phoneNum  entered on the merchant's site
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   */

  function CallMarkExpressCheckout($paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, $cancelURL, $shipToName, $shipToStreet, $shipToCity, $shipToState, $shipToCountryCode, $shipToZip, $shipToStreet2, $phoneNum
  ) {
       //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       // Construct the parameter string that describes the SetExpressCheckout API call in the shortcut implementation
//       $nvpstr = "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=" . $paymentAmount;
//       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=" . $paymentType;
//       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&RETURNURL=" . $returnURL;
//       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CANCELURL=" . $cancelURL;
//       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=" . $currencyCodeType;
//       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&ADDROVERRIDE=1";
//       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME=" . $shipToName;
//       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET=" . $shipToStreet;
//       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET2=" . $shipToStreet2;
//       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY=" . $shipToCity;
//       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE=" . $shipToState;
//       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=" . $shipToCountryCode;
//       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP=" . $shipToZip;
//       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM=" . $phoneNum;


       $nvpstr = "&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
               &RETURNURL=http://localhost/trash/pp/response.php
               &CANCELURL=http://localhost/trash/pp/response.php
               &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
               &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=10% Decaf Kona Blend Coffee
               &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=623083
               &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=Size: 8.8-oz
               &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=9.95
               &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=2
               &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1=Coffee Filter bags
               &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1=623084
               &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC1=Size: Two 24-piece boxes
               &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1=39.70
               &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1=2
               &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=99.30
               &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=2.58
               &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=3.00
               &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT=2.99
               &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT=-3.00
               &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT=1.00
               &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=105.87
               &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD
               &ALLOWNOTE=1";
       $_SESSION["currencyCodeType"] = $currencyCodeType;
       $_SESSION["PaymentType"] = $paymentType;

       //'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
       //' Make the API call to PayPal
       //' If the API call succeded, then redirect the buyer to PayPal to begin to authorize payment.  
       //' If an error occured, show the resulting errors
       //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       $resArray = hash_call("SetExpressCheckout", $nvpstr);
       echo '<pre>';print_r($resArray);exit;
       $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
       if ($ack == "SUCCESS" || $ack == "SUCCESSWITHWARNING") {
            $token = urldecode($resArray["TOKEN"]);
            $_SESSION['TOKEN'] = $token;
       }

       return $resArray;
  }

  /*
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for the GetExpressCheckoutDetails API Call.
    '
    ' Inputs:
    '       None
    ' Returns:
    '       The NVP Collection object of the GetExpressCheckoutDetails Call Response.
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   */

  function GetShippingDetails($token) {
       //'--------------------------------------------------------------
       //' At this point, the buyer has completed authorizing the payment
       //' at PayPal.  The function will call PayPal to obtain the details
       //' of the authorization, incuding any shipping information of the
       //' buyer.  Remember, the authorization is not a completed transaction
       //' at this state - the buyer still needs an additional step to finalize
       //' the transaction
       //'--------------------------------------------------------------
       //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
       //' Build a second API request to PayPal, using the token as the
       //'  ID to get the details on the payment authorization
       //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
       $nvpstr = "&TOKEN=" . $token;

       //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
       //' Make the API call and store the results in an array.  
       //'  If the call was a success, show the authorization details, and provide
       //'  an action to complete the payment.  
       //'  If failed, show the error
       //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
       $resArray = hash_call("GetExpressCheckoutDetails", $nvpstr);
       $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
       if ($ack == "SUCCESS" || $ack == "SUCCESSWITHWARNING") {
            $_SESSION['payer_id'] = $resArray['PAYERID'];
       }
       return $resArray;
  }

  /*
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for the GetExpressCheckoutDetails API Call.
    '
    ' Inputs:
    '       sBNCode:    The BN code used by PayPal to track the transactions from a given shopping cart.
    ' Returns:
    '       The NVP Collection object of the GetExpressCheckoutDetails Call Response.
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   */

  function ConfirmPayment($FinalPaymentAmt) {
       /* Gather the information to make the final call to
         finalize the PayPal payment.  The variable nvpstr
         holds the name value pairs
        */


       //Format the other parameters that were stored in the session from the previous calls    
       $token = urlencode($_SESSION['TOKEN']);
       $paymentType = urlencode($_SESSION['PaymentType']);
       $currencyCodeType = urlencode($_SESSION['currencyCodeType']);
       $payerID = urlencode($_SESSION['payer_id']);

       $serverName = urlencode($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

       $nvpstr = '&TOKEN=' . $token . '&PAYERID=' . $payerID . '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=' . $paymentType . '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=' . $FinalPaymentAmt;
       $nvpstr .= '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=' . $currencyCodeType . '&IPADDRESS=' . $serverName;

       /* Make the call to PayPal to finalize payment
         If an error occured, show the resulting errors
        */
       $resArray = hash_call("DoExpressCheckoutPayment", $nvpstr);

       /* Display the API response back to the browser.
         If the response from PayPal was a success, display the response parameters'
         If the response was an error, display the errors received using APIError.php.
        */
       $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);

       return $resArray;
  }

  /*
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose:  This function makes a DoDirectPayment API call
    '
    ' Inputs:
    '       paymentType:        paymentType has to be one of the following values: Sale or Order or Authorization
    '       paymentAmount:      total value of the shopping cart
    '       currencyCode:       currency code value the PayPal API
    '       firstName:          first name as it appears on credit card
    '       lastName:           last name as it appears on credit card
    '       street:             buyer's street address line as it appears on credit card
    '       city:               buyer's city
    '       state:              buyer's state
    '       countryCode:        buyer's country code
    '       zip:                buyer's zip
    '       creditCardType:     buyer's credit card type (i.e. Visa, MasterCard ... )
    '       creditCardNumber:   buyers credit card number without any spaces, dashes or any other characters
    '       expDate:            credit card expiration date
    '       cvv2:               Card Verification Value
    '
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '
    ' Returns:
    '       The NVP Collection object of the DoDirectPayment Call Response.
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   */

  function DirectPayment($paymentType, $paymentAmount, $creditCardType, $creditCardNumber, $expDate, $cvv2, $firstName, $lastName, $street, $city, $state, $zip, $countryCode, $currencyCode) {
       //Construct the parameter string that describes DoDirectPayment
       $nvpstr = "&AMT=" . $paymentAmount;
       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CURRENCYCODE=" . $currencyCode;
       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTACTION=" . $paymentType;
       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CREDITCARDTYPE=" . $creditCardType;
       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&ACCT=" . $creditCardNumber;
       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&EXPDATE=" . $expDate;
       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CVV2=" . $cvv2;
       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&FIRSTNAME=" . $firstName;
       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&LASTNAME=" . $lastName;
       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&STREET=" . $street;
       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CITY=" . $city;
       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&STATE=" . $state;
       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&COUNTRYCODE=" . $countryCode;
       $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&IPADDRESS=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

       $resArray = hash_call("DoDirectPayment", $nvpstr);

       return $resArray;
  }

  /**
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   * hash_call: Function to perform the API call to PayPal using API signature
   * @methodName is name of API  method.
   * @nvpStr is nvp string.
   * returns an associtive array containing the response from the server.
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   */
  function hash_call($methodName, $nvpStr) {

       //declaring of global variables
       global $API_Endpoint, $version, $API_UserName, $API_Password, $API_Signature;
       global $USE_PROXY, $PROXY_HOST, $PROXY_PORT;
       global $gv_ApiErrorURL;
       global $sBNCode;

       //setting the curl parameters.
       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

       //turning off the server and peer verification(TrustManager Concept).
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

       //if USE_PROXY constant set to TRUE in Constants.php, then only proxy will be enabled.
       //Set proxy name to PROXY_HOST and port number to PROXY_PORT in constants.php 
       if ($USE_PROXY)
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $PROXY_HOST . ":" . $PROXY_PORT);

       //NVPRequest for submitting to server
       $nvpreq = "METHOD=" . urlencode($methodName) . "&VERSION=" . urlencode($version) . "&PWD=" . urlencode($API_Password) . "&USER=" . urlencode($API_UserName) . "&SIGNATURE=" . urlencode($API_Signature) . $nvpStr . "&BUTTONSOURCE=" . urlencode($sBNCode);

       //setting the nvpreq as POST FIELD to curl
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

       //getting response from server
       $response = curl_exec($ch);

       //convrting NVPResponse to an Associative Array
       $nvpResArray = deformatNVP($response);
       $nvpReqArray = deformatNVP($nvpreq);
       $_SESSION['nvpReqArray'] = $nvpReqArray;

       if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            // moving to display page to display curl errors
            $_SESSION['curl_error_no'] = curl_errno($ch);
            $_SESSION['curl_error_msg'] = curl_error($ch);

            //Execute the Error handling module to display errors. 
       } else {
            //closing the curl
            curl_close($ch);
       }

       return $nvpResArray;
  }

  /* '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Purpose: Redirects to PayPal.com site.
    Inputs:  NVP string.
    Returns:
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   */

  function RedirectToPayPal($token) {
       global $PAYPAL_URL;

       // Redirect to paypal.com here
       $payPalURL = $PAYPAL_URL . $token;
       echo $payPalURL;exit;
       header("Location: " . $payPalURL);
  }

  /* '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   * This function will take NVPString and convert it to an Associative Array and it will decode the response.
   * It is usefull to search for a particular key and displaying arrays.
   * @nvpstr is NVPString.
   * @nvpArray is Associative Array.
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   */

  function deformatNVP($nvpstr) {
       $intial = 0;
       $nvpArray = array();

       while (strlen($nvpstr)) {
            //postion of Key
            $keypos = strpos($nvpstr, '=');
            //position of value
            $valuepos = strpos($nvpstr, '&') ? strpos($nvpstr, '&') : strlen($nvpstr);

            /* getting the Key and Value values and storing in a Associative Array */
            $keyval = substr($nvpstr, $intial, $keypos);
            $valval = substr($nvpstr, $keypos + 1, $valuepos - $keypos - 1);
            //decoding the respose
            $nvpArray[urldecode($keyval)] = urldecode($valval);
            $nvpstr = substr($nvpstr, $valuepos + 1, strlen($nvpstr));
       }
       return $nvpArray;
  }

?>
```

I install curl using

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

bu still the issue.Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Look at the php.ini (info php) and see if curl_enable is true

Comment: Please don't share sensitive information in your question

Comment: @davidnoronha-thanks

Comment: @roy -thanks for ur reply.let me check

Comment: didnt you restart http server after curl installing?

Comment: Please share your output of `php -m`